# SQL syntax error on JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbo->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT count(character_name)
            FROM playercharacter
            JOIN character
            ON (playercharacter.character_id = character.character_id)
            WHERE user_id = :user_id");
```

giving me

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character ON
>   (playercharacter.character_id = character.character_id)' at line 3' in
>   /home/content/50/10835750/html/dogdays/game/private.php:43 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/content/50/10835750/html/dogdays/game/private.php(43):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/content/50/10835750/html/dogdays/game/private.php on line 43

Comment: why u people are keeping discouraging valid questions just because "u think" you are way smarter than the person or the question ? it is a very valid question for others that might find that "character" is a reserved keyword. i think you just like giving away minuses, maybe just because facebook has only pluses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`character` is a Reserved Keyword and happens to be the name of your table. In order to avoid syntax error, the table name should be escaped using backticks. Ex,

```
SELECT  count(character_name) 
FROM    playercharacter JOIN `character` 
            ON (playercharacter.character_id = `character`.character_id) 
WHERE   user_id = :user_id
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the table name that is not on the *Reserved Keyword List* to prevent the same error from getting back again on the future.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="If+you+have+the+privilege+to+alter+the+table%2C+change+the+column+name+that+is+not+on+the+Reserved+Keyword+List" %)